I came across a tutorial I wanted to follow and while making my character I realized I couldn't find anywhere how to make a cube go rounded like this

Anyone know how to make a cube go like this. Really would appreciate any help

It's probably got a Subdiv Surface modifier on it but it's impossible to say without more details. At least add a link to the tutorial you're following and an image of the whole window via the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender. Then edit your question and add the details.

It's usually good to describe in detail what you're looking for. This seems to be a bad screenshot to illustrate what you want to make. And please [edit] your title as well: be descriptive but succinct. You can copy most of it to the body of your question.
